# can achieve "Tabs in Fragment of Navigational Drawer" using action bar sherlock

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, navigation-drawer

[image: Tabs in Fragment of Navigational Drawer]

I wanted to achieved the screen as above in the image. i already have implemented Navigational drawer successfully. but here I have to use two tabs on a fragment. All examples says how to use tabs on a n Activity. Can anybody give clue about how to implement tabs on a Faragment? thanks in advanced!.

the image should be rotate 90 degrees in clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Android support Lib v4 provides a class called [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html).
There is an example provided for Tabs in a nested fragment.